# Add objects to NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewController with many UITableViewCells inside, each of which has a checkbox. Within the custom UITableViewCell class there is a method which happens when the checkbox is checked. I also have an NSMutableArray as a property of the UITableViewController and I want to add an object to it everytime the checkbox is checked but I am having trouble accessing the other class. Some help please?

Comment: after lots of searching & writing logic for this problem, i found the perfect solution on [apple developer demo for TableViewCell Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html) for it. try it.

Comment: @pawan - You shouldn't have to search that hard, since this question is asked about once a day, and the solution is trivial.

Comment: @HotLicks i did not search for this question, i was telling my experience , when i had started my career as ios app developer. its about 3 years ago , i found this solution.

Comment: @pawan - Yeah, and the question's been asked once a day for about 4 years, that I know of.

Comment: @HotLicks absolutely correct. thats why i posted  it as comment not answer. i think this question should be closed with duplicate flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have custom cell class, create a cell's delegate.

```
@class MyCustomTableViewCell;

@protocol MyCustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)cell:(MyCustomTableViewCell *)cell checkboxValueDidChange:(BOOL)checked;
@end

@interface MyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <MyCustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` assign your controller as table view cell's delegate. Having this, you'll receive callback.

```
- (void)cell:(MyCustomTableViewCell *)cell checkboxValueDidChange:(BOOL)checked {
    // get cell's index path if you need
    if (checked) {
        [self.myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:myIndex];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.